# Randomised stopping time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stopping-times

At the beginning of Ferguson's notes on Optimal Stopping ([https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Stopping/Contents.html](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etom/Stopping/Contents.html)) a general definition of stopping rule is introduced. Denoting with $N$ the random time at which stopping occurs, associated with the observed process $\{X_n\}$, it is defined in terms of its probability of stopping at time $n$, given observations $X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n$, that is in terms of the functions $\phi_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\mathbb{P}(N=n|N\geq n,X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)$, where $0\leq\phi_n\leq 1$. The author calls this a randomised stopping rule. According to this definition, a randomised stopping rule is not in general a stopping time, since the event of stopping is not determined by the process $X$ alone (as usual, I call a stopping time a random time $N$ such that $\{N=n\}\in\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$). Is my understanding correct? Thanks for sharing any advice. I found several definitions of randomised stopping rules on the internet, but there seems to be little agreement, and this seems to be the most general I encountered so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A randomized stopping rule corresponds to a stopping time for an enlarged filtration. Let $U_1,U_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. variables that are uniform in $[0,1]$ and independent of the process $\{X_j\}_{j \ge 1}$. Let $\mathcal G_n$ be the $\sigma$-field generated by $X_1,U_1,\dots,X_n,U_n$.
Then the stopping time $\tau$ (I prefer that notation rather than $N$) can be defined by
$$\tau:=\min\{n \ge 1 :\,  U_n\le \phi_n(X_1,\dots,X_n)\}\,.$$
Clearly, $\tau$ is a stopping time for the filtration $\{\mathcal G_n\}$,
and it satisfies
$$\mathbb{P}(\tau=n|\tau\geq n,X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n) =\phi_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \,.$$

Comment: I see, thank you! This construction you mention also shows that, in expectation, stopping with respect to the one with the enlarged filtration is equivalent to stopping with respect to the randomised one (assuming some reward function $y_n(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$). So technically there is nothing to gain, in expectation, from allowing randomised stopping times, if I understand correctly. One can just restrict optimal stopping to non-randomised rules with no loss of generality.

Comment: It also means that there is no need to worry about randomized stopping rules, as they are completely equivalent to the construction with enlarged filtration I mentioned. If some authors prefer that language, there is no loss in rigor.